# how to combine contents of two files based on key columns in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I've two files with 3 identical columns and 4th a different one.

**File A**

```
a b c 100
e f g 50
h i j 25
```

**File B**

```
a b c 200
e f g 20
h i j 15
```

How can files `A` and `B` be combined to look like file `C`?

**File C**

```
a b c 100 200
e f g 50 20
h i j 25 15
```

--UPDATE--

I've used the solutions provided by Jotne an Kent but both of the script's output have . (dot) instead of comma. it looks like

```
  a,b,c,100.200 
  e,f,g,50.20
```

Comment: Together with updating the question, provide comments to the answers. Also, indicate exactly what command you used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2,$3]=$4;next} {print $0,a[$1,$2,$3]}' B A > C
cat C
a b c 100 200
e f g 50 20
h i j 25 15
```

Comment: +1: I made a slight change in using `SUBSEP` as delimiter instead of `FS`.

Comment: @jaypal Thanks, looks more clean.

Answer (score 0):

If they had just a column in common, `join` could make it. But let's use it and then parse the output:

```
$ join <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
a b c 100 b c 200
e f g 50 f g 20
h i j 25 i j 15
```

This joined based on the first column. Now, let's use `cut` to get everything but columns 5 and 6:

```
$ join <(sort f1) <(sort f2) | cut -d' ' -f1-4,7
a b c 100 200
e f g 50 20
h i j 25 15
```

Note the usage of `sort` to sort the files, because `join` needs files to be sorted to work. With the sample data given it worked without `sort`, but added for consistency.

Comment: True! I was aware of it but given that the sample input worked without `sort`... I didn't add it. But you are right, updated with `<(sort file)` all around. Thanks!

Comment: @jaypal well funny thing in that case is that `join f1 f2 | cut -d' ' -f1-4,7` would make it, as well as with the original input. So apparently in this case giving more options to `join` kind of breaks it. Updating.

Comment: It will only work if the keys are lined up in both files at same line number. If you swap them around it will break. `;)`